Multiple inicio RClone
Necesito crear un archivo bash sh para poder montar varias unidades con rclone.
Sin embargo no logro que se inicien todas porque al ejecutarse la primera se queda como en pausa y no pasa al siguiente, si se inicia el montado y funciona pero solo con el primero no se que pueda ser ya que no manejo mucho de rclone, este es mi script
#! /bin/sh
rclone mount --config "/home/k0zd3r/.config/rclone/rclone.conf" --allow-other --quiet --poll-interval 20s --dir-cache-time 24h --vfs-read-chunk-size 32M --umask 002 --vfs-read-chunk-size-limit off --vfs-cache-mode writes --rc-addr=127.0.0.1:5001 --rc Unidad1:/ /home/k0zd3r/files/Disk1
rclone mount --config "/home/k0zd3r/.config/rclone/rclone.conf" --allow-other --quiet --poll-interval 20s --dir-cache-time 24h --vfs-read-chunk-size 32M --umask 002 --vfs-read-chunk-size-limit off --vfs-cache-mode writes --rc-addr=127.0.0.1:5002 --rc Unidad2:/ /home/k0zd3r/files/Disk2
rclone mount --config "/home/k0zd3r/.config/rclone/rclone.conf" --allow-other --quiet --poll-interval 20s --dir-cache-time 24h --vfs-read-chunk-size 32M --umask 002 --vfs-read-chunk-size-limit off --vfs-cache-mode writes --rc-addr=127.0.0.1:5003 --rc Unidad3:/ /home/k0zd3r/files/Disk3
rclone mount --config "/home/k0zd3r/.config/rclone/rclone.conf" --allow-other --quiet --poll-interval 20s --dir-cache-time 24h --vfs-read-chunk-size 32M --umask 002 --vfs-read-chunk-size-limit off --vfs-cache-mode writes --rc-addr=127.0.0.1:5004 --rc Unidad4:/ /home/k0zd3r/files/Disk4

También cuando ejecuto linea por linea manualmente se monta pero se queda como pausada la consola ssh, debo cerrar la ventana y volver a abrir otra para que pueda ejecutar una adicional que hace lo mismo

¿Haz aplicado una condicional & entre rclone para ejecutar este comando en segundo plano?
